# Nested Application Setting in App Service not being applied

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-5

I have a .NET 5.0 application deployed to a Linux app service on Azure. I have set a nested application setting but it is not being applied.

The Application Setting is `ImageProcessingConfig__CompressionQualityPercentage`

appsettings.json contains:

```
    "ImageProcessingConfig": {     
       "CompressionQualityPercentage": 5,
        ...
```

Program class has the following:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) 
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

ConfigureServices method in Startup:

```
            var imageProcessingOptions = new ImageProcessingOptions ();
            Configuration.Bind (ImageProcessingOptions.ImageProcessingConfig, imageProcessingOptions);
            services.AddScoped<IImageProcessor> (c => new ImageProcessor (imageProcessingOptions));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was the result of using Configuration.Bind() in ConfigureServices(). It is working as expected after the following change there:

```
           Configuration.Bind (ImageProcessingOptions.ImageProcessingConfig, imageProcessingOptions);
           imageProcessingOptions.CompressionQualityPercentage = int.Parse(Configuration["ImageProcessingConfig:CompressionQualityPercentage"]);
           services.AddScoped<IImageProcessor> (c => new ImageProcessor (imageProcessingOptions));
```